# Internal network and iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have a server that is behind a firewall provided by the phone company.  I'm logging entries like the entries below.  Do these entries imply that the connection attempts are making it through the phone company firewall?

I should not see any connection attempts from IP addresses outside the USA, yet these IP addresses appears to be.

```
Feb  8 02:36:32 avserver2 kernel: [14880192.644132] DROP-0-250: IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=113.106.135.143 DST=192.168.0.250 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=47819 PROTO=TCP SPT=53426 DPT=1433 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Feb  8 02:36:32 avserver2 kernel: [14880192.644242] DROP-0-250: IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=103.253.145.186 DST=192.168.0.250 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=47821 PROTO=TCP SPT=61953 DPT=8165 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
Feb  8 02:36:32 avserver2 kernel: [14880192.644489] DROP-0-250: IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=192.241.201.145 DST=192.168.0.250 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=255 ID=47823 PROTO=TCP SPT=54987 DPT=2376 WINDOW=0 RES=0x00 RST URGP=0
```

Comment: We can't say anything without more detailed information. How the network is set up? How firewall is configured which logged this? For now I can at most suppose your server is 192.168.0.250 assigned to eth0. These packets may be actually some leftovers from prior conversations; notice RST flag on them. Port numbers (SPT and DPT) look arbitrary; are these used somewhere in your configuration?

Comment: The phone company delivers the public Internet to their router.  Their router handles the IP phones and provides some switch ports that provide the 192.168.0.0/24 network.  Workstations, the server, etc. connect to that network and the router provides DHCP.  The server is 192.168.0.250.  I've been logging these entries with iptables and then dropping them.  These entries are continually being logged.  I'm dropping these packets, but I'm wondering if the logging shows that these requests are getting through the phone company's hardware (phone/Internet) device?

Comment: They are going through, but it could be these must go through, because your side wanted them. It is impossible to say without knowing which services are running on this server. For example, FTP service uses arbitrary TCP ports in addition to port 21; SIP service uses arbitrary UDP ports for RTP in addition to usual 5060 and so on; a proper firewall will detect this and permit packets when they are expected.

Comment: Thank you very much for reviewing this topic.  In other words, if the server is actively trying to connect to these IP addresses, then the traffic would be expected.  If nothing on the server is actively initiating the connections, then the firewall is permitting the traffic to get through to the server.  The only services on the server are SSH (port 22), MySQL (3306) and SMB (445).  All of these should only be accessed from the local 192.168.0.0/24 network and never from a public IP and these are not actively initiating the connections.

Comment: Then these stray packets shouldn't be expected. You might still check `ss -lnpt` for listening ports (read ss manual for other diagnostic info it might output) to be sure there's really only ones you know.

Comment: Thank you for the help